# Flipping different data in the same activity when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

This is my first question to stackoverflow, so please do not see my acceptance rate.

What I am trying to create is a quiz in android. Here I am having the same layout where I have a question and 3 answers. I have a next button at the bottom. When I click on that the same layout should get loaded with new question and options for it.

I am thinking of how to do it. I saw something called view flipper, but can anyone tell me the exact solution for this?

Here is my code

```
public class TriviaQuiz extends Activity  {


        Trivia trivias = TourDescription.currentTour.getTriviaArray().get(0);



Here trvias is an object which contains all the data. 



}

// send the trivias to the activity where I set the question and options
public void playquiz(View v) {


        Intent quizIntent = new Intent(TriviaQuiz.this, Quiz.class);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


        bundle.putSerializable("trivia", trivias);


        quizIntent.putExtras(bundle);


        startActivity(quizIntent);



    }



public class Quiz extends Activity


]
```

In this last activity I have the layout and the next button. Hope it is clear now.

Note:Here am trying to update the array value at get(0)

Please help me a way for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this, call a method with the array index and then inside the method set the values as needed. Next when tap on the button,update the value of array index in the required manner.

Answer (score 0):

You should update values on the button click for the next question. Do you see any problem with this approach?

Comment: That is what I am trying, how to update the data? here is how I am setting the dara.  
  questionTxt.setText(question);
  optionsTxt1.setText(option1);
  optionsTxt2.setText(option1);
  optionsTxt3.setText(option1);

Comment: if you are getting exception in updating the values on button click then do it thru handler .....

Comment: Still I dint reach that level, I yet to update my data. I am thinking how to do it

Comment: I got the answer for this, will post the answer after 8 hours